# dbApply Example in R Documentation does not work

Tags: mysql, r

I set up a MySQL database using XAMPP and having been doing some very basic things. I tried using dbApply, just to replicate the example in the R documentation. But the result does not look correct. I'm expecting the result to be a list of 3 items:  the mpg percentiles for 4, 6, and 8 cylinder cars.  Here is the code:

```
con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), host = "localhost",dbname="rbaseball"
         ,user = "root", password = "")
dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars, overwrite = TRUE)
res <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars ORDER BY cyl") 
dbApply(res, INDEX="cyl", FUN = function(x,grp) {quantile(x$mpg)})
```

Here is the output.  It is a list of 30 items.  For all but 2 of the lists, the 5 percentiles are exactly the same, indicating that there was just one number in the vector of data it used to calculate the percentiles.  This doesn't seem like it is the output that the R example was attempting to get.

```
$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 24.4 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 22.8 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
32.4 32.4 32.4 32.4 32.4 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
30.4 30.4 30.4 30.4 30.4 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 33.9 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
21.5 21.5 21.5 21.5 21.5 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
27.3 27.3 27.3 27.3 27.3 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  26   26   26   26   26 

$`4.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
30.4 30.4 30.4 30.4 30.4 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
21.0 21.1 21.2 21.3 21.4 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  21   21   21   21   21 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 21.4 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
18.1 18.1 18.1 18.1 18.1 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 

$`6.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
17.8 17.8 17.8 17.8 17.8 

$`8.000000`
   0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
18.70 18.95 19.20 19.45 19.70 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
14.3 14.3 14.3 14.3 14.3 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
16.4 16.4 16.4 16.4 16.4 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
17.3 17.3 17.3 17.3 17.3 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
15.2 15.2 15.2 15.2 15.2 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
10.4 10.4 10.4 10.4 10.4 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
10.4 10.4 10.4 10.4 10.4 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
14.7 14.7 14.7 14.7 14.7 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
15.5 15.5 15.5 15.5 15.5 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
15.2 15.2 15.2 15.2 15.2 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
13.3 13.3 13.3 13.3 13.3 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 19.2 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 15.8 

$`8.000000`
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
  15   15   15   15   15
```

Comment: Please show and not just tell your output. Is it different than `lapply(mtcars$cyl, FUN=function(x) quantile(mtcars[mtcars$cyl == x,c("mpg")]))`? Per the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RMySQL/versions/0.5-4/topics/dbApply), the returned value of `dbApply` is: *A list with as many elements as there were groups in the result set.*

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  The output I am getting, which I edited the post to add, does not match what I get from running your code above.  As for _A list with as many elements as there were groups in the result set._:  I am expecting a list of 3 elements as there are 3 different cylinder groups.